# Spotify Local Server API

Tags: javascript, api, oauth, spotify

So I am tapping into the spotilocal.com:4380 server that runs under spotify and that facebook uses to update / interface with the clients desktop app.

through some sniffing in the network panel I found how to get a JSON string back

```
http://8440.spotilocal.com:4380/remote/status.json?cors=&csrf=____&oauth=____
```

The question that i have is – how can I get the csrf and oauth tokens without manually inspecting my network panel when on facebook.

Comment: You can't. That's why `csrf` is *cross site request forgery* (protection) - to prevent this.

Comment: valid.. but I can only imagine that facebook is doing the handshake somewhere so there might be a way to do my own

Comment: If there's a handshake like that, it'd be on the backends. Unless you're going to crack their security and sniff the backend's HTTP connections, you're not going to get info about the handshake.

Comment: no it is all client side... I am sure of it

Comment: It used internally, not intended for public use, therefore the handshake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the oAuth, you have to get them from Facebook or Spotify.

As for the CSRF token, you have to make a request to "spotilocal:xxxx/simplecsrf/token.json", this will return a {token:...}.

However, this token can only be returned if it comes from a specific set of referrers. This is obviously done to prevent people from starting any music on any people's computer.

You can have a look on this thing I found online:
http://code.google.com/p/spotify-local-api/source/browse/trunk/SpotifyLocalAPI/SpotifyAPI.cs?r=2

Comment: I just worked on something myself too, you can have a look here:
https://github.com/jsgoupil/house-audio/blob/master/AudioBase/SpotifyWebApi.cs

Answer (score 0):

If you issue a GET from your client to https://open.spotify.com/token then the response JSON object will have an oAuth token inside it.